# Fabric.io: new app does not show up in the dashboard

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android, google-fabric

For some reason we needed to change the package-id of our existing android application. We already use Fabric for Crashlytics.

I'm trying to bring that new app up in the Fabric dashboard, but it's not showing there, despite the device log showing no issues (as fas as I can see): [device log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0tDV.png)

Any ideas why the new package-id isn't visible in our dashboard?

Best,
Sven

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Try doing a clean, and then fresh build and run and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your support, appreciate it! Sadly that didn't help. I did that before already. And as you can see from my device log, there is already a settings request for the new package-id and the backend sends a response. So I would assume that I can see an app for that package-id, but that's not the case...

Comment: Yea, I asked because we saw the app in a partially configured state, but not fully activated. Try enabling debug mode to see if that triggers the build to come through to activate the app: https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html

Comment: I've already added debug mode before, in order to see all that stuff in the device log?! But I removed the app from the device, cleaned and re-build the app and installed it. Same result, can't see the app in the dashboard...

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was from a run only of the event. For some reason, we're still only seeing the build, do you have any logic that would have disabled Fabric for certain build types?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Hmm, very strange, but you should be all set now with the app.

Comment: Did you do anything on your side? Because I didn't, but I luckily can see the app now in the dashboard.

But I need to add another app very soon, and I don't know what I should do any other, compared to this time...

Comment: Yep, I made a manual change to fix this. For the next app, I'd try the set of steps from the installation page: https://fabric.io/kits, then have a build and run and see how it goes. It's possible that a race condition caused the issue, but I'm still testing that theory locally.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I got a similar problem on my ends. I'm using Fastlane which successfully upload the app but I see nothing on the dashboard.

Comment: Do you see your app in Fabric's dashboard?

Comment: @svzi, I found similar problem , it is our case, I changed old package name to new package name, changed in Manifest.xml then I forgot to change in App's level build.gradle file to change 'applicationId'. Then I got it in Dashboard. May you be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will have a look at it, when I need this again!

Comment: Fabric Beta is not good :-/

Answer (score 5):

I experienced a very similar issue to this when building an app with multiple flavours. The solution is to manually specify the package name, and not let Fabric try to automatically grab it, as it tries very hard to "stick" your old package name.

There is a [full post available](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/using-fabric-answers-beta-crashlytics-with-app-flavours/) (disclaimer: my site), but essentially you need to use:

```
    Fabric.with(
        Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(Crashlytics())
            .appIdentifier(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
            .build()
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include all dependencies on their dedicated gradle.build and meta in manifest file. Next is to throw a force runtime error on your device with internet connection also do not forget to initialize it first with `Fabric.with(this,new Crashlytics())`. If this doesn't work try to download and install Fabric for Android plugin in Android Studio, restart the IDE and you will see a fabric icon above. Start it and select your package name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, in the log I clearly see that the Crashlytics is in use.

```
I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: <ID>
```

But I cannot see my project on the dashboard, and always redirect to the tutorial.

After a **Build-Clean** and an Android studio **restart**, build and run the app again to my phone, and voilá, it finds itself. Now working, without any change.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After hours of researches I resolve this for my application.

First: After adding new flavour, I make changes in Firebase console (added new app in existing project, with production SHA1, changed google-services.json).

After that app does not show in fabric dashboard and fabric plugin in Android Studio. Problem was resolved after linking new app in crashlitycs in firebase console. And after that check your roles, must have Owner role (on Firebase Console Project).